# Add CSS to iframe page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

In simple terms, I have uploaded a video to Google Drive that I wish to embed onto my website. I retrieved an embed code from the shared-video page for my video on Google drive:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DK7pele_HjWUR6Ym9KNFU5YTQ/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

As you can see, this is simply an iframe to the URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DK7pele_HjWUR6Ym9KNFU5YTQ/preview

When visiting the above URL, I am presented with a full-screen view of a YouTube-style video player (after clicking the play-button in the centre of the image), and a **very** frustrating 'Pop out' arrow symbol (to the top-right of the page). I do **NOT** want the users of my website to link back to the Google Drive shared-video page for my video (i.e. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DK7pele_HjWUR6Ym9KNFU5YTQ/view). All I want to do is remove the annoying 'Pop out' arrow-symbol option.

Using Google Chrome, I did a little test by right-clicking on the 'Pop out' arrow symbol and clicked on 'Inspect element' - this brought me to the page's code, with an irrelevant piece selected. I managed to find the fade-style button/bar's div element - the code for this is:

```
<div class="drive-viewer-v2-toolstrip" role="toolbar" style="width: 52px; right: 0px; opacity: 0;"></div>
```

I edited the code to see if adding this simple piece of CSS code: `display: none`, would work:

```
<div class="drive-viewer-v2-toolstrip" role="toolbar" style="width: 52px; right: 0px; opacity: 0;display: none;"></div>
```

And it did - when I hovered my cursor over the 'Pop out' arrow image, it didn't display. When I clicked in its area, instead of opening the Google Drive shared-video page, it played the video.

The only problem with this is that it was a test editing the code on the actual video's page. What I **REALLY** want to know is: is there **ANY** way, using **ANY** programming language (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, etc.), to remove this frustrating 'Pop out' arrow on MY page via the iframe? I've been spending hours trying to use javascript code, css code, even php code from answers to similar questions and even different websites with NO luck.

I want to add CSS to the page as if I were adding it to the official video-page (the page my website iframes to via the embed code given by Google) - I think this CSS is correct:

```
.drive-viewer-v2-toolstrip {
display: none;
}
```

I understand something to do with 'cross-domain' rules prevents this code from having any effect on the iframe page - but is there **any** way, even a hack, to simply add that code OR remove the 'Pop out' symbol image?!

As you can tell, I'm NOT an experienced programmer, so some support would be greatly appreciated.

Notes:
- The video used is only for example purposes - it's not the actual video but I assume I can just change the iframe src to the actual video's URL.
- To see my test page, go here: `http://freemedia.x10.mx/index.html` (sorry - due to my current account restrictions I'm unable to post two different links as I don't have "10 reputation").

Comment: You can't do that due to Same-Origin policies, implemented by browsers. What you can do is to fetch the HTML using PHP, parse the HTML, find that element and then edit the `style` attribute and spit out the new HTML. Which might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly embedding the video using HTML5's `<video>` tag (which is what is inside your iframe anyway)?

```
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; left: 0px; top: -480px; transform: none;" src="https://r10---sn-4g57kney.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&amp;shardbypass=yes&amp;cmbypass=yes&amp;id=951765eacbdee2ee&amp;itag=18&amp;source=webdrive&amp;app=docs&amp;ip=217.5.178.213&amp;ipbits=0&amp;expire=1432754244&amp;sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&amp;signature=691BAE82BA1FE4D4084DCCB9C1EBDA134AF4312B.A789605BB07CC90CBAE60AD24A9631022835B6DC&amp;key=ck2&amp;mm=30&amp;ms=nxu&amp;mt=1432750367&amp;mv=u&amp;nh=IgpwcjAxLmZyYTAzKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&amp;pl=23&amp;cpn=jL7UCwA73YsFunXs&amp;c=WEB&amp;cver=html5"></video>
```

### Edit:

I just tested this but it does not work since the `src` does not directly point towards a video file but rather many `POST` parameters which google works on to create the video when embedded in an iframe. Can you download the video file?

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I did try your method and it did in fact work (in Google Chrome anyway) - the only problem is that the YouTube-style player is lost and you have to right-click to play/pause the video. Also - I can download the video via the actual video-share page (not the embed/iframe src URL) - is this what you mean?

Test page using your code: http://freemedia.x10.mx/test.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. You can upload the video file to your own server - or some free server with ftp access - and use the video tag independently from what google offers. You should get the standard HTML 5 video controls then.

Comment: I have two questions regarding your answer: 1) How did you get the URL that is in the 'src' part of the 'video' tag? 2) If I were to find a HTML5 player that allowed the selection of different qualities (for example: 360p, 480p, 720p, 1080p) similar to how the YouTube players ability to select different qualities, would I be able to do this using just this URL/src? Or does this URL only link to a specific-quality version of the video? (as I know that, when you upload a 1080p video to Google Drive, Google Drive creates multiple copies in different qualities). Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: No, it links only to one specific file. For solutions how to offer connection quality dependent files, you need to do further research on your own. This is also way beyond the scope of your initial question.

Comment: My apologies. Thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is a brutal way to do this:

```
<div class="iframe_hide_poop">
<div class="magic"></div>
<iframe src="...."></iframe>

</div>
```

then the css part is:

```
.iframe_hide_poop{
 position:relative;
//add your stuff
}
.iframe_hide_poop iframe{
  position:relative; 
  //add your stuff
}
.magic{
  position:absolute;
  width:80px; 
  height:80px;
  top:20px; //adjust the value
  right:20px;//adjust the value
  background-color:#000;
}
```

In this way, there will be an 80X80 black area "above" the pop-up button preventing users seeing pop-up, or you can change the width of the .magic to be 100%, it will show as a thin banner if you think it looks better.