# Anyone know how to hide/remove Popout of Google Drive Embed Video?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

anyone here have the same problem with 
`class="drive-viewer-v2-toolstrip"`

I tried a lot of things but somehow I can't kill it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.drive-viewer-v2-toolstrip').remove();
});
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The embeded code for the video is inside an iframe and because of that you won't be able to access its content from your page. in this case the jquery code you are using does not have visibility of the content of the iframe and this is due to same origin policies. 
The context of your page is different from the context of the page inside the iframe. here you can find information about this topic: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: Is there a loophole for this? I need to remove it so my users can't get the file id :(

Comment: check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490108/add-css-to-iframe-page

Comment: I already have and still there are no answers. Even with the css part, its a bad answer because it will manually put a black box on top right screen

Answer (score 0):

One way maybe to show a logo icon there as an overlay with z-index set to render above the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it 100% flawless, use a link like this but just replace it with your own google doc id: https://video.google.com/get_player?docid=0B67eSO00NnBBTzNjV2hDaW9DUHc&ps=docs&partnerid=30&cc_load_policy=1 (if it doesn't work, just post the link onto facebook first, then let it automatically make a preview, then just get the link from the source code of that preview!)